# Refuse to load JS in Dart

Tags: javascript, dart, google-chrome-app, content-security-policy

In my web page for Dart amount this script:

```
<script src="https://test.net/test/test.js"></script>
```

but when you launch the application it gives me the following error:

> Refused to load the script 'https://test.net/test/test.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I also set the Content Security Policy in manifest without any result:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://test.net/test/"
```

Does anyone know how to fix?

**Edit**

This answer [Loading external javascript in google chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781851/loading-external-javascript-in-google-chrome-extension) in Dart does not work.

Manifest:

```
..."permissions":["tabs","https://test.net/test/"],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://test.net/test/; object-src 'self'",
"content_scripts": [
{
  "js": ["https://test.net/test/test.js"]
}
]...
```

Code:

```
JsObject spark=context['spark'];
print(spark);
spark.callMethod('login',["{username: 'test@email.com', password: 'test'}"]);
```

Result:

> null
>
> Exception: The null object does not have a method 'callMethod'.

Dart does not support script injection dynamically:

> [Will there be a dynamic code injection for dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449489/will-there-be-a-dynamic-code-injection-for-dart)

So how do you change the Content Security Policy?

**Edit 2**

Chrome reports this error when I install the app:

[image]

Comment: Add the url to your manifest.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading external javascript in google chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781851/loading-external-javascript-in-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: I voted to close this question because it has been answered already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781851/loading-external-javascript-in-google-chrome-extension

Comment: This answer in Dart does not work

Comment: Why not? Please post your full example.

Comment: I think because Dart does not support script injection dynamically. Edit post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a package app for Chrome you can not use the fields `"content_scripts"`, `"content_security_policy"` and `"tabs"`.

Dart also does not support script injection dynamically. As explained here:

> [Will there be a dynamic code injection for dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449489/will-there-be-a-dynamic-code-injection-for-dart)

To use JS code must save it locally, import it into your html code:

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

and use the library [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:js) to interact with the code js, like:

```
  test=context['test'];
  test.callMethod("login",["var1","var2",...,callback]);
```